# How to get the "absolute value" of a raster cell in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, reclassify

I have a raster map (-100 to +100) and I need to get all the minus values as absolute values (-100=100; -99=99...). How can I do this? Is it something like reclassify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [Raster Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html) to do this. Square the pixel values to ensure all values are positive, and then extract the square roots to get back original number. Something like this:

```
sqrt ( myraster@1 * myraster@1 )
```