# Modulus in QGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I have the same question like the one aked here:
[How to get the “absolute value” of a raster cell in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41294/how-to-get-the-absolute-value-of-a-raster-cell-in-qgis)

I came up with the same solution for the problem some time ago. However I showed this solution to a software developer some days ago, and he was very amused. Is there a build in function in QGIS to acquire the modulus of a real number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raster calculator does not have a built-in modulus function, but you can try:

```
 ( "ras1@1" > 0 ) * "ras1@1" +  ( "ras1@1" < 0 ) * ( -1 ) * "ras1@1"
```

- If the cell value is negative, `( "ras1@1" > 0 )` returns `0`, while `( "ras1@1" < 0 )` returns `1`. The output cell value is `( -1 ) * "ras1@1"`.
- If the cell value is positive, `( "ras1@1" > 0 )` returns `1`, while `( "ras1@1" < 0 )` returns `0`. The output cell value is `"ras1@1"`.
- If the cell value is `0`, both `( "ras1@1" > 0 )` and `( "ras1@1" < 0 )` return `0`. The output cell value is `0`, too.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the geoalgorithm [r.mapcalc](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.mapcalc.html) in the GRASS section of he Processing Toolbox. The number of supported operators and functions is by far bigger than the Raster Calculator:

```
 Operator   Meaning                    Type        Precedence
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 -          negation                   Arithmetic  12
 ~          one's complement           Bitwise     12
 !          not                        Logical     12
 ^          exponentiation             Arithmetic  11
 %          modulus                    Arithmetic  10
 /          division                   Arithmetic  10
 *          multiplication             Arithmetic  10
 +          addition                   Arithmetic   9
 -          subtraction                Arithmetic   9
 <<         left shift                 Bitwise      8
 >>         right shift                Bitwise      8
 >>>        right shift (unsigned)     Bitwise      8
 >          greater than               Logical      7
 >=         greater than or equal      Logical      7
 <          less than                  Logical      7
 <=         less than or equal         Logical      7
 ==         equal                      Logical      6
 !=         not equal                  Logical      6
 &          bitwise and                Bitwise      5
 |          bitwise or                 Bitwise      4
 &&         logical and                Logical      3
 &&&        logical and[1]             Logical      3
 ||         logical or                 Logical      2
 |||        logical or[1]              Logical      2
 ?:         conditional                Logical      1



function                description                                     type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
abs(x)                  return absolute value of x                      *
acos(x)                 inverse cosine of x (result is in degrees)      F
asin(x)                 inverse sine of x (result is in degrees)        F
atan(x)                 inverse tangent of x (result is in degrees)     F
atan(x,y)               inverse tangent of y/x (result is in degrees)   F
cos(x)                  cosine of x (x is in degrees)                   F
double(x)               convert x to double-precision floating point    F
eval([x,y,...,]z)       evaluate values of listed expr, pass results to z
exp(x)                  exponential function of x                       F
exp(x,y)                x to the power y                                F
float(x)                convert x to single-precision floating point    F
graph(x,x1,y1[x2,y2..]) convert the x to a y based on points in a graph F
graph2(x,x1[,x2,..],y1[,y2..])
                        alternative form of graph()                     F
if                      decision options:                               *
if(x)                   1 if x not zero, 0 otherwise
if(x,a)                 a if x not zero, 0 otherwise
if(x,a,b)               a if x not zero, b otherwise
if(x,a,b,c)             a if x > 0, b if x is zero, c if x < 0
int(x)                  convert x to integer [ truncates ]              I
isnull(x)               check if x = NULL
log(x)                  natural log of x                                F
log(x,b)                log of x base b                                 F
max(x,y[,z...])         largest value of those listed                   *
median(x,y[,z...])      median value of those listed                    *
min(x,y[,z...])         smallest value of those listed                  *
mode(x,y[,z...])        mode value of those listed                      *
nmax(x,y[,z...])        largest value of those listed, excluding NULLs  *
nmedian(x,y[,z...])     median value of those listed, excluding NULLs   *
nmin(x,y[,z...])        smallest value of those listed, excluding NULLs *
nmode(x,y[,z...])       mode value of those listed, excluding NULLs     *
not(x)                  1 if x is zero, 0 otherwise
pow(x,y)                x to the power y                                *
rand(a,b)               random value x : a <= x < b                     *
round(x)                round x to nearest integer                      I
round(x,y)              round x to nearest multiple of y
round(x,y,z)            round x to nearest y*i+z for some integer i
sin(x)                  sine of x (x is in degrees)                     F
sqrt(x)                 square root of x                                F
tan(x)                  tangent of x (x is in degrees)                  F
xor(x,y)                exclusive-or (XOR) of x and y                   I

Internal variables:
 row()                  current row of moving window                    I
 col()                  current col of moving window                    I
 nrows()                number of rows in computation region            I
 ncols()                number of columns in computation region         I
 x()                    current x-coordinate of moving window           F
 y()                    current y-coordinate of moving window           F
 ewres()                current east-west resolution                    F
 nsres()                current north-south resolution                  F
 area()                 area of current cell in square meters           F
 null()                 NULL value
```

[image]